# Javascript Execute message when mouse is on left side of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anybody know how to make it so when the the mouse is close or at the left side of the page that it will send a message in **javascript.** Basically so when you take your mouse and move it too close to the left side it will just use alert("Example");.

Thanks, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna Haha, still a bit rusty with Javascript. But yeah.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cFGEo

Comment: Sorry , i should have put it in answer

Answer (score 2):

Working fiddle [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cFGEo)

HTML

```
<div class="menu hide"></div>
```

SCRIPT

Call Custom function when mouse is leaving ,and in that function ,if mouse is hovered from left side of Window at least by 20px then do task you want.

```
var menu = $('.menu');
var menuTimeout;

$(window).on('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  if (e.pageX < 20 || menu.is(':hover')) {
    // Show the menu if mouse is within 20 pixels from the left or we are hovering over it
    clearTimeout(menuTimeout);
    menuTimeout = null;       
    alert("left side")
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You expect something like this

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

    $( document ).bind( "mousemove", function( event ) {
        if( (event.pageX) < 10 )
        {
            alert("Example");
        }
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```